# Need to change a computer name back to its old name on a domain

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-domain

I had a problem witha computer I was trying to join to the domain. I gave it a different name than the one it was supposed to have but now I have to go back to the original name. However now I cant go back as when I attempt to rename it it gives me an error sayying the name is already in use.

I have tried deleting and recreating the name in the AD.
I have also flushed the dns cache on the machine but that has not helped.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super annoying AD issue. You say you have tried deleting and recreating the name in AD, which I believe I have used in the past to solve a similar issue. What you might want to attempt is leaving the domain, deleting both the new and old names from AD then changing the computer name to the correct name and rejoining the domain without first adding it back to active directory. When you join the computer should be added as a new active directory computer